# Throwing RecognitionException from grammar actions

Tags: antlr4

I have a "custom" requirement to validate function calls in a language at parse time (i.e. after successfully matching a function call). I know that this is normally semantics-related hence usually performed later but once again, a "custom" requirement...

Currently, I use an action where I add function validation code upon successful matching. I tried throwing a plain new RecognitionException instance when validation failed but apparently the DefaultErrorStrategy class hard-codes the types of errors it handles and limits itself to RecognitionException sub-classes.

The trouble is I would like to re-use the whole default error handling mechanism yet use my own exception type (or at least message).

Question: how can I either throw a plain RecognitionException instance or a sub-type of it with a custom message, different of the existing sub-types, YET re-use the default error handling mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, after investigating a bit...

`DefaultErrorStrategy` **DOES** already handle any other `RecognitionException` sub-types, simply by notifying the parser's registered error listeners. It's clearly stated in `reportError()`'s javadoc: *All other types: calls {@link Parser#notifyErrorListeners} to report the exception*, not to mention pretty clear in the code itsef: [DefaultErrorStrategy.java](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.java).

The thing that mislead me at first was that in the case of any other `RecognitionException` subtype, a message (that I would rather not have!) was also printed to stderr.